# Синонимизировать [спам]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метки:

- [spam](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) (26 вопросов, нет описания).
- [спам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc) (11 вопросов, нет описания).

Предлагаю их синонимизировать в сторону [спам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc). Русский термин употребляется больше в самих вопросах, а кроме того есть традиция делать русскую метку главной, если метка не является названием языка/библиотеки/фреймворка/ и так далее.

Вручную синонимизировать не хотелось бы. В последнее время и так на главной много старых вопросов поднимается (например в процессе выпиливания [яндекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81) и [operator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator)), да и 26 вопросов не так уж и мало, руками это долго делать, а если учитывать то, что метку можно будет снова создать, вообще бесполезно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
updating post history, 32 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 26 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 25 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'spam': [spam] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 36
tag remapping of [спам] and [spam] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```